# UITableviewcell width not filling the screen

Tags: xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I don't know if this is a bug with AutoLayout or Xcode but I've realised that if I run my application on a device which isn't the same size as the device in my storyboard, the elements are adopting the incorrect size.

I.e. Selecting View as iPhone SE and running the application on an iPhone 7+ The size of my tableview is the width of an iPhone SE screen, this fixes itself when I reload the view and then it then adopts the width of the iPhone 7+ screen.

Just a note as well the table view doesn't have a fixed width and is pinned to the top, bottom, left and right with 0 spacing and also I'm changing the height of the cells programmatically in code if this could affect it at all as well.

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0QLbDLfJn6_YzljUGg4RTUwaTg

Comment: That is very weird... I assume your question is is this a bug or not?

Comment: How do you reload the view?

Comment: Yes and it's a tab based application so when i got to another view by selecting a tab icon and go back it sorts itself out one sec i'll attach a video now

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Xcode. I'll attempt to recreate it later.

Comment: I've added a video so you can both see the problem, hopefully this doesn't affect my application when it's on the app store. @jabbathehutt1234

Comment: @Tunds You should make use of TestFlight to make sure the AppStore version works correctly before releasing ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Views that come from a xib (or storyboard) have their IB frame values when they are created, before they are added to the view hierarchy. So a case like you describe is probably that something is accessing a view loaded from a xib before it has become part of the layout process and resized.

This would also explain why it's fixed when you go away and come back. The first time, it got the values before they were final, but the second time the values are already final and correct.

Layout code called from`viewDidLoad()` for view controllers, or `awakeFromNib()` or `initWith(coder:)` for views is the likely cause. Layout code called from `viewDidLoad()` is especially problematic because it was fine up to iPhone 5s, but would now cause this problem.

It's impossible to say what exactly the issue just from this. From the NSLog statements visible in the video, the issue is whatever code calls that "weather view width". That is being called too early in the layout process. It needs to go in `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to make sure the correct values are ready for whatever calculation is dependent on that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to recreate this. I would recommend double checking for any updates for Xcode and the Developer tools (`softwareupdate --install -a`).

Incase you haven't, restart Xcode.

**EDIT:** Disregard this answer, please read [Mike Sand's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033873/5619332) post.

Comment: Tried that and XCode doesn't need updating since it's up to date

Comment: Weird. Clear the cache maybe?

Comment: This is not an xcode bug. You can recreate this by adding a subview of width `self.view.frame.size.width` in `viewDidLoad`. The subview will always have whatever the width was in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try self.view.layoutIfNeeded in viewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear